# how to transfer bower package ownership?

Tags: bower, package-managers, ownership

Some time ago I registered a bower package and submitted a [pull request to original repo](https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/webL10n/pull/40).

How to transfer package ownership? Is updating repo address enough?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you have to [`unregister`](http://bower.io/docs/api/#unregister) a package first, before anybody else can [`register`](http://bower.io/docs/api/#register) it back again.

In special security cases, ask the team at opensource@twitter.com.